# React Js: Using refs instead of an Id

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I was using ID to access the `span` element then I found out that we can't use IDs and instead we have to use `refs` but after running this code an error is showing up `Uncaught ReferenceError: heroSkills is not defined`

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.heroSkills = React.createRef();
        let typewriter = new Typewriter(heroSkills, {
            loop: true
        });
    render() {
       return <span ref={this.heroSkills}></span>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.heroSkills = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let typewriter = new Typewriter(this.heroSkills.instance, {
      loop: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <span ref={this.heroSkills}></span>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.heroSkills = React.createRef();
    let typewriter = new Typewriter(this.heroSkills.current, {
      loop: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <span ref={this.heroSkills} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When a ref is passed to an element in render, a reference to the node
>   becomes accessible at the current attribute of the ref.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Instead of:

```
let typewriter = new Typewriter(heroSkills, {
  loop: true
});
```

do:

```
let typewriter = new Typewriter(this.heroSkills.current, {
  loop: true
});
```